# Storm topology failure while running on production

Tags: java, runtime-error, thrift, apache-storm

Hi I'm having a issue with running storm cluster. It is similar to

My Topology is defined as :

```
            package com.abc.newsclassification;

            import StormBase.KnowledgeGraph.ClassifierBolt;
            import StormBase.KnowledgeGraph.ClientSpecificTwitterSpout;
            import StormBase.KnowledgeGraph.LiveTwitterSpout;
            import StormBase.KnowledgeGraph.NewsTwitterSpout;
            import StormBase.KnowledgeGraph.TwitterTrainingBolt;
            import StormBase.KnowledgeGraph.UrlExtractorBolt;
            import backtype.storm.Config;
            import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
            import backtype.storm.StormSubmitter;
            import backtype.storm.generated.AlreadyAliveException;
            import backtype.storm.generated.InvalidTopologyException;
            import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
            import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;

            public class ClassifierTopology {

                public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

        // add a spout
                    builder.setSpout("spout", new NewsTwitterSpout(), 1);
                // configure 
                    Config conf = new Config();
                    conf.setDebug(false);

                    // submit it to the cluster, or submit it locally
                        conf.setMaxTaskParallelism(10);
                        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
                                    System.out.println(conf.entrySet());
                        cluster.submitTopology("testTopology", conf,
                                builder.createTopology());

                }
            }

     ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ** END OF FILE **
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

pom.xml:

```
            <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
                <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

                <groupId>StormBase</groupId>
                <artifactId>KnowledgeGraph</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>

                <name>KnowledgeGraph</name>
                <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

                <properties>
                    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                </properties>

                <repositories>
                    <repository>
                        <id>clojars.org</id>
                        <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
                    </repository>
                </repositories>
                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <source>1.6</source>
                                <target>1.6</target>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <archive>
                                    <manifest>
                                        <mainClass>com.abc.newsclassification.ClassifierTopology</mainClass>
                                    </manifest>
                                </archive>
                                <descriptorRefs>
                                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                                </descriptorRefs>
                            </configuration>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>single</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.1</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>


                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.0</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>storm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
                        <version>0.8.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.3</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>

                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>

                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>

                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.yammer.metrics</groupId>
                        <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
                        <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
                        <version>0.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.jopt-simple</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jopt-simple</artifactId>
                        <version>4.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.netflix.curator</groupId>
                        <artifactId>curator-test</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.5</version>

                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.5</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.1</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <scope>compile</scope>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.languagetool</groupId>
                        <artifactId>language-en</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.1</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.5</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
                        <version>4.6.0</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
                        <version>3.6.2</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lucene-snowball</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.3</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
                        <version>4.6.0</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.gravity</groupId>
                        <artifactId>goose</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.23</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
                        <artifactId>weka-dev</artifactId>
                        <version>3.7.9</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.0.8</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.javatuples</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javatuples</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>opennlp-tools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.3</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.2</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.lang</artifactId>
                        <version>2.6</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.0</version>
                        <classifier>models</classifier>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>edu.washington.cs.knowitall.stanford-corenlp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>stanford-postag-models</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.5</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.code.google-collections</groupId>
                        <artifactId>google-collect</artifactId>
                        <version>snapshot-20071022</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.googlecode.concurrent-trees</groupId>
                        <artifactId>concurrent-trees</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.16</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.3</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hectorclient</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hector-core</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1-0</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>me.prettyprint</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hector-test</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0-5</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>FBKeyWords</groupId>
                        <artifactId>FBKeyWords</artifactId>
                        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>KeyWordExtractor</groupId>
                        <artifactId>KeyWordExtractor</artifactId>
                        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.6</version>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>
            </project>



            ---------------------------------------------------------------

            ** END OF pom.xml **
            ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

The following is the error I'm getting:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [topology.workers=3, topology.debug=false]
                Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
                    at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:21)
                    at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:70)
                    at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:41)
                    at com.tookitaki.newsclassification.ClassifierTopology.main(ClassifierTopology.java:92)
                Caused by: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
                    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:183)
                    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
                    at backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin.connect(SimpleTransportPlugin.java:66)
                    at backtype.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.<init>(ThriftClient.java:46)
                    at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.<init>(NimbusClient.java:30)
                    at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.<init>(NimbusClient.java:26)
                    at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:19)
                    ... 3 more
                Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
                    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
                    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
                    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
                    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
                    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
                    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
                    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:178)
                    ... 9 more
```

Please let me know which version of storm/other packages should I use, or if there are any other problem causing this Error. Any sugesstion is welcome.

Comment: The pom.xml above is mentioning Storm 0.8.2, is there a specific reason you use this version? The latest released version is 0.9.1. 

Also, could you provide the exact command you execute that generates the error? With localcluster we just need to invoke the main(), there is no need to package the topology with maven "assembly" nor submitting it with "storm jar ...". If you tried that maybe that's what's causing the issue since it would try to connect to a (probably non existing) Nimbus on localhost.

Answer (score 3):

I also meet the same problem.

I check the iptables and supervisors and nimbus, but it isn't their problem.

I tried to submit half of the topology (by removing some kind of bolts) and it passed.

I check the nimbus.log and find a error line indicating that the thrift buffer is full , so you can change your "storm.yaml" with config:

```
nimbus.thrift.max_buffer_size: 20480000
```

Comment: I had problem with the permissions in nimbus. thanks to tell where I can check

Comment: Fixed it for me.  I wonder, however.  Is there a file that needs deleted?  Will this just extend the timespan between problems?

Answer (score 2):

Old question but worth answering.....I am using Storm 1.0.1.

You should check if incoming port 6627 is open on Nimbus/Master from Storm Workers.

I got the same error when Storm workers was not able to connect to Nimbus and showing error on source download failure error from master.

Storm Master or Nimbus runs Thrift on a port 6627

You can check using command "netstat -nat"  on your master/nimbus

```
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6627                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your topology wasn't submitted, because the storm client couldn't connect to Nimbus, in which case it wouldn't be anything in your code.  Make sure nimbus is running and the storm command can access it, i.e. to do a "storm list".

Comment: Thanks Steve for your effort. It was a problem with log4j related dependency. I've got a work out

Comment: you should have then let others informed that the issue was resolved

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem, in my case problem is related about to zookeeper location settings.

I moved zookeeper nodes different servers and i forgot the change zookeeper locations in storm.yaml so nimbus can not get information from topologies and other storm-supervisor nodes.

After correction of wrong location of zookeeper nodes, the problem is solved.

As i understand your problem is solved but i want to mentioned my case for other readers.